# Maxims that have to do with persistence?

Tags: idioms, popular-refrains, proverbs

I am looking for idiomatic expressions that convey the value of persistence, such as a long, drawn-out battle where the victor is necessarily the person who simply outlasted the other. I know there is at least one good one, but I can't think of any.

EDIT: Upon reading SethJeffrey's answer, I just realized I am actually looking for a maxim, not an idiom. I want something a little bit more substantial than an idiom. Here's an example I just made up: "It's not the obstacles on the roadway, it's the length of the track." This isn't very good...I'm looking for something like that, only a real maxim.

Comment: If at first you don't succeed, try, try again.

Comment: @StoneyB -- Not exactly what I am looking for...I added more detail to my description above about what I mean by "persistence." Also, isn't that more of an adage than an idiom?

Comment: How would you use this expression? I think we need a sentence with a gap where the saying would go. One possibility is  "to the victor belong the spoils."  -- http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/32/messages/793.html

Comment: @chaslyfromUK -- That's not really what I'm looking for either. This idiom does not really communicate the importance of patience and stamina, as much as it basically says, "winner take all."

Comment: You still haven't described how the phrased is used. Is it said to someone to encourage them?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK -- Perhaps, but not necessarily. I am just trying to describe the type of situation where persistence is the only route to success.

Comment: "Never, never, never give up." - Winston Churchill (or possibly Thomas the Tank Engine & friends)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yep, that's Winnie.  Thomas the Tank Engine said, "We shall fight on the beaches, we shall fight on the landing grounds, ...."

Comment: I suggest you look at quotations relating to *tenacity*: http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/keywords/tenacity.html, http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/tenacity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rosalind Ferguson, *The Facts on File Book of Proverbs* (983) has several good suggestions along these lines:

> It's dogged as does it.
>
> Have at it, and have it.
>
> Slow but sure wins the race.
>
> The race is not to the swift nor the battle to the strong. [Ecclesiastes 9:11]
>
> Feather by feather the goose is plucked.
>
> Little strokes fell great oaks.

Comment: *Little **strokes***

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks for pointing out the error. I think this answer set an all-time record for me for typos per line in a posted answer. I've already fixed four now.

Comment: @SvenYargs -- these are interesting suggestions and I will look into them. I am only familiar with the third idiom, "Slow and steady wins the race." This idiom is not what I am looking for; it suggests the need to work slowly and carefully instead of rushing to get a task done. My context is less about working slowly and more about lasting longer. The fifth and sixth suggestions are also not appropriate—they basically communicate the same message as the third suggestion.

Comment: @SvenYargs -- Can you explain the meaning of, "The race is not to the swift nor the battle to the strong"? Also, can you explain the meaning of, "Have at it, and have it"?

Comment: The context of the saying in Ecclesiastes is an observation about the uncertainty of life: "Again I saw that under the sun the race is not to the swift, nor the battle to the strong, nor bread to the wise, nor riches to the intelligent, nor favor to those with knowledge, but time and chance happen to them all." The point here, I believe, is that a person's or entity's advantages going into a battle or other contest are merely advantages, not guarantees of success. However, the quoted phrase has been taken as an encouragement to persevere and to make one's own luck, as much as is possible.

Comment: "Have at it, and have it" is simply a pithy way of saying that if you want something (that's the "have it" part of the saying) you had best go after it wholeheartedly ("have at it"). The key here is that you don't simply give it a shot and then abandon the effort if progress seems slow or nonexistent. A total commitment to achieving the goal provides the best chance for eventual success.

Comment: Okay, I understand the meaning of the Ecclesiastes maxim now. It is applicable. However it is slightly too broad for my liking. I apologize for being so critical, but I could have sworn that there is a maxim out there that describes exactly what I am talking about.

Comment: @Kyle 'Slow and steady wins the race' _is_ what you are looking for. It doesn't just mean 'slow and careful is better than rushing' but also that 'perseverance' or 'persistence' is the winning factor.

Comment: @Mitch -- Yeah...the more I think about it, I think you are right.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of the proposals have been mainly proverbs or maxims. Here are some phrases that are hopefully more idiomatic and figurative.

> Keep slogging / churning / hacking away.
>
> Keep one's nose to the grindstone.
>
> Eager beaver. (not exactly persistence, more like enthusiasm)

Comment: @SethJeffrey -- You've answered my question; the first two certainly are idioms that have to do with persistence. However, upon reading your answer, I just realized I am actually looking for a maxim.  The first two phrases basically communicate, "Continue to work hard." But I actually want something a little bit more substantial than that. Here's an example I just made up: "It's not the obstacles on the roadway, it's the length of the track." I'm looking for something like that, only a real maxim.

Comment: Ah I see, then I think Sven's answers are already pretty comprehensive, particularly "Slow and steady wins the race."

Answer (score 0):

[No pain, no gain.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/no+pain,+no+gain)

There is no reward without sacrifice.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. We are looking for more substantial answers that are mostly your own words instead of unattributed content copied from elsewhere.

Comment: @tchrist While your criticisms are constructive, merely boilerplating them under every answer you are unsatisfied with will most likely have the results you are now seeing. I suggest you refrain from further salting answers with criticism without actually doing anything whatsoever to improve the answer or the site. Take a breather, thanks.

Comment: @tchrist Thanks, again, really. But my point is made. Leave the youngest posts alone... they may very well improve. There are a lot of 3 day old or older posts that could use some pointers. How about giving those a little love instead of this.... whatever this is? Your comments are premature. This is the problem. These answers are less than a day old. Attempting to moderate this way will only aggrivate users. Please consider a lighter touch and less efficiency in your comments. Thanks.

Comment: A non-answer will not become an answer simply for having aged three days. Please fix this.

Comment: @tchrist Again, I'm now begging you... leave the new posts alone. Your moderation of young posts serves no purpose but to pad your participation counts. Cease your boilerplating. Cease your obsession with answers that have not matured. Any users that have answered dozens of questions are constantly returning to those answers to improve them. 3 hours is not enough time for an answer to age before you leap to take advantage of whatever points you get for editing an answer and not changing it or adding copypasta commented criticisms. Again, every answer you spammed was about 3 hours old. Chill.

Comment: @chillin You've posted half a hundred minimal "answers" of fairly low quality and you accuse tchrist of spamming? And what does the age of the answer have to do with its problems? Because the answer is recent, that lets you off the hook for not answering the question properly?

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew  Yes, in fact. Answers are editable. It is common for an answer to take days or weeks to mature. The rating system is plenty good moderation for imature answers, but the boilerplating of tchrist, and the all too familiar way senior site users interfere with newer users' only serves them, the mods. My request is reasonable. Hours old answers should be unmolested with boilerplated criticisms.

Comment: And I will continue to post minimal answers, and accept the moderation of all users, not just the score-padders. The hidden agenda of moderators, to appear to wish to improve the site by gaming their points pouncing on the newest posts, unwritten in any list of rules of the site, is not my agenda. My agenda is to answer the posted question as simply as possible.

Comment: @chillin You have 24 answers posted since Aug 13. Most are scored at 1 or lower and many of your answers are on posts you've already answered. Your track record doesn't suggest that your answers will materially improve no matter how long they stick around. And if you think tchrist's behaviour here is meant to pad some kind of score, you sorely misunderstand what kind of user tchrist is. Check out [his user profile,](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2085/tchrist) and you'll see he's earned every single rep point honestly.

Comment: Enough: You need to step back and look at what you're doing wrong, not argue about it. Your *ad hominem* attacks upon established users for carrying out the tasks they are supposed to be carrying out serve no constructive purpose; there is no such thing as "points to be gamed" by carrying out those activities. Your contributions which are not up to site standards will be dealt with accordingly. If you continue to produce low quality non-answers, you may be banned from making further answers. We don't want a bunch of thoughtless one-liners; those are not useful contributions.

Comment: @tchrist Trouble is you are all beyond reproach. You spammed a bunch of my immature answers, and do not wish to give an inch that you may have possibly salted this field so completely there is no recovery. No one is perfect. Swallow your pride, and stop bullying users (not you personally, this goes to all mods everywhere).

Comment: **You are the one who is spamming** by supplying not just more than one answer per question, but indeed more than one non-answer. The general principle is one question, one answer — and make it a real one, not these impoverished one-liners of no substantive quality. Since you refuse to accept constructive advice and have become contumacious in the face of people attempting to help you, you no longer have the excuse to pretend that you were not warned as matters run their course here.

Comment: @tchrist Respectfully, I refuse your requests. I do not accept your criticisms as valid. These are not non-answers, but valid and novel at the time posted. There are no such rules for participation on this site that short answers are invalid. While I returned today to improve these answers, I instead discovered the treachery of overmoderation and the inability of the mod to accept any responsibility nor compromise. This is bullying. Your abuse has conviced me to let these answers be. They will stand as they are.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking to the moral of one of the fables of Jean de La Fontaine [The lion and the rat](http://oaks.nvg.org/fonta2.html#lioandrat) - 1668.

*Original french text: « Patience et longueur de temps font plus que force ni que rage»*

- Translation 1 : **By time and toil we sever What strength and rage could never.**
- Translation 2 : **Patience and the fullness of time do more than force or fury.**

Answer (score -1):

> [Mighty oaks from little acorns grow.](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/247100.html)

This is seen in many close forms:

- Even the mighty oak was once a nut like you
- The mighty oak was once a nut that stood its ground.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. We are looking for more substantial answers that are mostly your own words instead of unattributed content copied from elsewhere.

Comment: @tchrist Thank you for your input! Your comment, however, highlights two problems. First of all, answers are editable, and it is common form for the author to continue to improve the answer. Further, you are able to edit and improve the answer; nothing is stopping you. More often than not, well-meaning individuals like yourself comment on answers without improving them, offering constructive criticism. This is not, the first answer I have posted. If you wish, improve or even delete it. But try not to be so quick on the draw with trying to improve new answers with constructive criticism.

Comment: Perhaps answers should be given some time to age, to allow the author to adjust and improve the post? Of course, this is meta and I fully expect a well-meaning offering of how to improve what I'm now attempting to do... get the -moderators- to give authors of recent posts some breathing room. Thanks.

Comment: Your so-called answer is a link only, containing no words of your own. Link-only answers are not answers.  Furthermore, we are looking for more substantial here that five little words. If you wish to improve your answers, merge these into just one, write in complete paragraphs using your own words, and make sure to summarize external content for that inevitable day when your link becomes useless.

Comment: @tchrist answer is less than 3 hours old when you decided to spam the page. Your criticisms become useless. How about you only try to improve answers that are, say, three days old or older? That sounds reasonable, doesn't it?

Comment: @chillin I'm not sure where you get the idea that it's reasonable for us to assume that an answer's quality will improve after 3 hours or even 3 days. In my experience most posts are never improved.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew I get that idea by your access to a users' activity. I'm not sure where you get the idea it is unreasonable to wait to criticize an immature answer.  Why is it unreasonable to restrict your attempts to improve users' answers to those that have aged a week or more? Most of the thinnest answers are older than 3 days. Are those answers not as important? By moderators' behavior, it appears that is so.

Comment: I don't have special access to any user's activity. I base my views on what I've seen in my 5 years here. Take a random sample of posts on the site: Answers that get edited after a few hours (by the OP) are the exception. My experience here doesn't justify any special treatment for new answers that are non-answers, especially considering you're filling up the page with every possible thing you can think of. Throwing the whole pot of noodles at the wall to see what sticks, then saying you'll clean it up later, is not the best way to approach this site.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew You have the access I have. Click on a user name, and you can see their activity. You leaped to defend your fellow, but he did not need defended. My grievance is not unreasonable. You are now arguing for your right to focus on posts that are very young at the expense of ignoring answers of similar quality that are older and far older. I am now wasting time begging to be unmolested so I can inprove my answers rather than improving my answers. Now I am heading to another site.

Answer (score -1):

> From humble beginnings come great things.

Origin is possibly [Job 8:7](http://biblehub.com/job/8-7.htm):

> Though your beginning was insignificant, Yet your end will increase greatly.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. We are looking for more substantial answers that are mostly your own words instead of unattributed content copied from elsewhere.

Comment: @tchrist see comment under "might oaks" answer. But by all means, keep up the good work! Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

> [Winners never quit, and quitters never win.](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090426211354AAztqnv)

Famously attributed to Vince Lombardi, the rule is if you want to win, you must not give up easily.

Answer (score -2):

> [It is the last straw that breaks the camel’s back.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_that_broke_the_camel%27s_back)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. We are looking for more substantial answers that are mostly your own words instead of unattributed content copied from elsewhere.