# Phrases or idioms for rebuilding something from the ground up

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Looking for phrases or idioms that can be used to describe a project so horribly done that there are no other options left but to demolish it and start it over again.

A sentence might be like:
"This project is so horribly done that I have no choice but to ......"

Comment: A very similar question: [feeling when you've failed in your job](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/278526/feeling-when-youve-failed-in-your-job)

Comment: You've already referenced a reasonable choice: "rebuild it from the ground up."

Answer (score 6):

I suggest

**Start from scratch**

> to begin from a point at which nothing has been done yet

*Nothing like this had ever been done before, so we had to start from scratch*.

OR

**Go back to the drawing board**

> to start over

*The company went back to the drawing board to make a better product*.

[Merriam-Webster]

Answer (score 1):

Another useful phrase for starting over is:

Go back to square one.